# Python - filtering list of strings based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to filter a list of strings based on multiple conditions.  Adding the output to a new list.

```
list1 = ['Bike', 'Street Bike', 'Custom Bike', 'Custom Street Bike', 'City Bike', 
'Cruiser Street Bike']

list2 = []
```

For the purposes of this example, I would like to extract the list items containing 'Street' & 'Bike'

I've tried the following method but it is returning all items on the list

```
list2 = [s for s in list1 if 'Street' and 'Bike' in s]
```

Expected output

```
   print(list2)  
   ['Street Bike', 'Custom Street Bike', 'Cruiser Street Bike']
```

Comment: You are missing `in s` for `"Street"`: `[s for s in list1 if 'Street' in s and 'Bike' in s]`

Comment: `[s for s in list1 if 'Street' and 'Bike' in s]` doesn't mean what you want for the same reason that `'Street' and 'Bike' in s` doesn't mean what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `if 'Street' and 'Bike' in s` evaluates to `True` all the time because what it is saying is:  `if 'Street'`, which is always `True` because `'Street'` is *Truthy*.  `and 'Bike' in s` which is also always `True` because 'Bike' is in all items in the list.  So you need

```
if 'Street' in s and 'Bike' in s:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change to

```
list2 = [s for s in list1 if 'Street' in s and 'Bike' in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that should work

```
list1 = ['Bike', 'Street Bike', 'Custom Bike', 'Custom Street Bike', 'City Bike', 'Cruiser Street Bike']
list2 = [s for s in list1 if 'Street' in s and 'Bike' in s]
print(list2) # Should Give this ['Street Bike', 'Custom Street Bike', 'Cruiser Street Bike']
```